# Strange convolution result

Tags: numpy

I want to understand how convolution works.
Here is some code:

```
import numpy
from scipy import misc

data = misc.imread("path_to_a_512x512_grayscale_image.png")
data = data/255.0

masque = numpy.array([[-1,0,1],
                      [-2,0,0],
                      [-1,0,1]],numpy.double)

def my_convolution(image, masque):
    hauteur,largeur = image.shape
    resultat = numpy.empty((hauteur,largeur))
    for y in range(1,hauteur-1):
        for x in range(1,largeur-1):
            pixel = 0.0
            for ym in range(3):
                for xm in range(3):
                    pixel += masque[ym,xm]*image[y-1+ym,x-1+ym]
            resultat[y,x]=pixel/9.0
    return resultat

my_result = my_convolution(data,masque)
plt.imshow(my_result, cmap='gray')
```

Result is not exactly the same with this basic method bellow. 
My previous method gives a a picture that seems to be darker

```
from scipy import signal
result2 = signal.convolve2d(data, masque)
result2 = result2[1:-1,1:-1]
plt.imshow(result2, cmap='gray')
```

Anyone call explain me with those 2 codes does not give the same result ?
I do not want to know which method is fastest, i know the first method is very ugly, i just want to understand.

Thanks

Comment: See if you are overflowing.

Comment: No i have checked, there are no overflow

Answer (score 0):

The convolution requires going backwards over one of the convolved functions, which means subtracting the inner indices, not adding them. Also, the second index in the `image` access expression has mismatched terms. So,

```
pixel += masque[ym,xm]*image[y-1+ym,x-1+ym]
```

should instead be more like

```
pixel += masque[ym,xm]*image[y-1-ym,x-1-xm]
```

For confirmation look at the [code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2526df72e5d4ca8bad6e2f4b3cbdfbc33e805865/scipy/signal/firfilter.c#L104) that runs when you call `signal.convolve2d` (specifically [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2526df72e5d4ca8bad6e2f4b3cbdfbc33e805865/scipy/signal/firfilter.c#L166) and [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2526df72e5d4ca8bad6e2f4b3cbdfbc33e805865/scipy/signal/firfilter.c#L191)). The inner indices match their respective outer indices, and they are subtracted during a convolution, not added.